# Keep left menu in every event node

Tags: views, 7

I created the event calendar using calendar view module. suppose If I click the particular event in calendar it will goes to particular event detail page but suddenly the left menu is disappear. How do I keep my left menu in all the event details pages?

Please assist me on this

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [Context](https://drupal.org/project/context) module to set the block active on content types and url wildcards (ex. /event/*). There are also much more conditions available with Context.

Comment: Thx kevin.I done this